# Error: Cannot find usable pandoc installation however it is installed in the system(macOS)

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, pandoc

I'm encountering an issue with RStudio where it is unable to recognize my pandoc installation when I try to install all packages using the command

```
devtools::load_all(".")
```

It throws the error:
Error: Cannot find usable pandoc installation

I have verified that pandoc is installed on my system, and even Rmarkdown is able to locate it using the command

> rmarkdown::find_pandoc()
> $version
> [1] ‘3.1.5’

this returns the version as '3.1.5'. Am I missing something or doing something wrong in here?

Comment: What's the full output of `find_pandoc()`? What directory is it finding the application? Are you running that command inside RStudio? Is that also where you are running `load_all()`? If you go to your terminal and run `pandoc --version`, can your terminal find the right program?

Comment: Yes terminal can find the pandoc version as: pandoc 3.1.5
full output of find_pandoc() is $version
[1] ‘3.1.5’

$dir
[1] "/usr/local/bin"